# How to create new site in Homestead without losing existing data?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vagrant, homestead, vagrant-provision

When I create a new Laravel 5 project, I edit my Homestead.yaml, my /etc/hosts and then do:

```
homestead halt

homestead up --provision
```

That makes my new site available but I lose my database tables for ALL of my other projects on the machine and have to manually reload them from backups.  I've searched around and it sounds like this is a known issue but I want to clarify that I'm not doing something stupid (which is likely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try to use `vagrant` command instead.

When you have your homestead machine running, try running `vagrant provision` in the directory where you have your `Vagrantfile`. It should reload the machine and your sites should be visible and any data shouldn't be removed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to lose existing data do as follows:

vagrant reload --provision

Trust me when i say that I tried all the advice and almost every time all my databases were destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

For a proper provisioning in Homestead machine, use `global-status` command of Vagrant to find out your Homestead's machine ID. This provides a result as the following image.

[image]

Then run `vagrant provision {your-machine-id}`.

Comment: This is destructive to the db

Comment: @kratos why would it be?

Comment: I tried it and it wiped out the databases. Not sure. Is this the same as vagrant reload --provision?

Comment: I never had that problem. Can't try now as I switched to Valet a few weeks ago.